# $f:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ is continuous, $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ , $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Then $f(x)=f^\prime(x)$ has soln in $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I know we can use Rolle's Theorem to get a point in $(0,1)$ such that $f^\prime(x)$ is zero at that point but don't know how to take it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $g(x)= e^{-x}f(x)$. Then $g(0)=g(1)=0$. And apply Rolle's theorem for $g(x)$.

Comment: Works, thanks. But how would you think of something like this?

Comment: @DeepishaSolanki Let's say you want to apply Rolle's to prove the problem. Then you want to write the equation $f(x)=f'(x)$ as a derivative of something being equal to zero. To do that first you take evreything on one side i.e. $f(x)-f'(x)=0$ this is not quite a derivative yet but when you multiply it with $e^{-x}$ then it becomes a derivative.

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks!